# Can a countable model of arithmetic have mutually non-definable numbers?

Tags: definition, model-theory, nonstandard-models

Let $M$ be a countable model of arithmetic (that satisfies PA). Can we have two numbers $c_1, c_2 \in M$ such that $c_1$ can not be defined in terms of $c_2$, and $c_2$ can not be defined in terms of $c_1$?

(When I say that $a$ can be defined in terms of $b$, I mean that we have a predicate in the language of arithmetic $\phi(x,y)$ such that only $a$ satisfies $\rho(z)=\phi(z,b)$.)

Start with $PA$, and add two symbols $c_1$, $c_2$. For each arithmetical predicate $\phi$, add the axiom $\phi(c_1,c_2) \implies (\exists c \neq c_1 \phi(c,c_2) \land \exists c \neq c_2 \phi(c_1,c))$. My question is equivalent then becomes equivalent to the question of whether this theory is consistient.

Interesting side note: I can show that the negation of continuum hypothesis implies this is true. Let $M$ be a model of PA equinumerous with real numbers. For each $c$ in $M$, there is a countable set $Def(c)$ of numbers definable in terms of $c$ (in the language of arithmetic). By the [axiom of symmetry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Freiling%27s_axiom_of_symmetry), there will be $c_1, c_2$ such that $c_1 \notin Def(c_2)$ and $c_2 \notin Def(c_1)$. Now take all the true statements of $M$ in the language of arithmetic plus symbols for $c_1$ and $c_2$ (we discard all the true statements involving the other nonstandard numbers). This will have a countable model $M'$, and since $c_1$ and $c_2$ cannot be defined in terms of each other in $M$, this will also be true in $M'$.

Comment: Just for fun, here's a *really stupid* argument in ZFC alone: the statement "For every countable theory, there is a countable model and a pair of elements which are mutually undefinable" is (appropriately phrased) $\Pi^1_2$; now force $\neg$CH, run your argument, and use [Shoenfield absoluteness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absoluteness#Shoenfield.27s_absoluteness_theorem).

Comment: @NoahSchweber You mean force $\lnot CH$ in $V$? That's great!

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "force $\neg$CH in $V$." Forcing takes a model of ZFC, and produces a larger model of ZFC with controlled properties. So we're really producing a *bigger* model, $V[G]$, in which CH holds; this tells us nothing about whether CH holds *in $V$*.

Comment: (You might object that there *is* no bigger model than $V$. This is right if we're taking $V$ to be the "actual" universe of all sets. To get around this, we can develop forcing *internally*, and produce a [*Boolean-valued* proper class structure $W$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean-valued_model#Boolean-valued_models_and_syntactic_forcing), interpreted in $V$, such that $W$ satisfies ZFC+$\neg$CH in the sense that each axiom of ZFC, and $\neg$CH, has truth value $\top$ in $W$.)

Comment: Assuming that there is any model with two mutually undefinable elements, can't we get a countable one from Lowenheim-Skolem? The number of pairs $\phi,\psi$ of formulas that could make the mutual definition is only countable. So the real question is only consistency, not count ability.

Comment: @CarlMummert Yes, that's absolutely right, and moreover for *any* theory $T$, the construction of a countable model of $T$ with countably many mutually non-definable elements is a basic application of indiscernibles (see my answer). I think all these complicated arguments people are coming up with are a bit silly!

Comment: @Alex Kruckman: thank you - I was afraid I was missing something.

Answer (score 4):

Yes.  Your use of the "axiom of symmetry" is totally unnecessary: just take $M$ to be any model of cardinality greater than $\aleph_1$, and the same argument works with no additional assumptions.  Explicitly, if $A\subset M$ is a set of cardinality $\aleph_1$, then there are at most $\aleph_1$ elements of $M$ that are definable from an element of $A$.  So there is some $c_1 \in M$ which is not definable from any element of $A$.  Since only countably many elements of $M$ are definable from $c_1$, some $c_2 \in A$ is not definable from $c_1$.  So neither of $c_1$ and $c_2$ is definable from the other.

Alternatively, instead of using uncountable models, you can just use compactness.  By compactness, it suffices to consider finitely many possible definitions at a time.  The argument above can then be carried out in any infinite model, taking $A$ to be a finite set of cardinality greater than the number of definitions you are considering.

Comment: How do you prove that  $c_1 \notin Def(c_2)$ and $c_2 \notin Def(c_1)$ for a model of cardinality greater than $\aleph_1$?

Comment: This is literally just the proof of the axiom of symmetry from the negation of CH.  That proof has nothing to do with real numbers; it's just a fact about sets of size greater than $\aleph_1$.

Comment: @celtschk: As mentioned in the question, the cardinality doesn't matter since you are just showing the consistency of a certain first-order theory.

Comment: Oh, I see assuming that no such $c_1, c_2$ exists, we can create an transfinite chain $a \in Def(b), b \in Def(c), c \in Def(d), \dots$. Once we have extended this to $\omega_1$ steps, we are done, since if a $c$ is not in the chain, $Def(c)$ must contain the chain, which is impossible. But if the cardinality of the model is greater than $\omega_1$ this is a contradiction!

Comment: You wouldn't happen to know how many mutually undefinable constants you *could* have, would you?

Comment: You can have any number (up to the size of your model).  Here's how you get three.  Start by taking a set $A$ of size $\aleph_2$ in a model $M$ of size $\aleph_3$.  Then at most $\aleph_2$ elements of $M$ are definable from any pair of elements of $A$, so there is some $m\in M$ definable from no pair of elements of $A$.  Now extend your language by adding a constant symbol for $m$ and use the argument of my answer to find two elements $a_1,a_2\in A$ which are mutually undefinable.  Then $m,a_1,$ and $a_2$ are mutually undefinable.

Comment: Continuing similarly by induction, you can get $n$ mutually undefinable elements for any $n\in\mathbb{N}$, and thus infinitely many by compactness.

Comment: @EricWofsey By a slightly different trick, you can get a triple from a model of size $\aleph_2$.

Answer (score 3):

Given any first-order theory $T$ (with infinite models) and any cardinal $\kappa\geq|T|$, there is a model of $T$ of size $\kappa$ containing a non-constant indiscernible sequence $I = (a_i)_{i\in \kappa}$ (so $a_i \neq a_j$ for all $i\neq j$). I claim that the elements of $I$ are mutually non-definable. Indeed, if there is some formula $\varphi(x,a_i)$ defining $a_j$, with $i<j$, then also $a_k$ satisfies $\varphi(x,a_i)$, so $a_k = a_j$, contradicting the fact that the sequence is non-constant.

Answer (score 2):

Here's yet another argument, this time via elementary chains and elementary counting:

---

We begin with an easy observation:

> **Lemma**: Suppose $\mathcal{A}\preccurlyeq\mathcal{B}$, $a\in\mathcal{A}, b\in\mathcal{B}$, with $b$ definable from $a$. Then $b\in\mathcal{A}$.

*Proof*: By elementarity, $\mathcal{A}$ contains a $b'$ with $\mathcal{A}\models\varphi(a, b')$, where $\varphi$ is the formula defining $b$ from $a$ in $\mathcal{B}$. By elementarity again, $\mathcal{B}\models\varphi(a, b')$ so $b=b'$. $\quad\Box$

As an easy corollary, consider a proper elementary sequence $(\mathcal{A}_\eta)_{\eta<\theta}$, let $a_\eta\in \mathcal{A}_\eta\setminus(\bigcup_{\alpha<\eta}\mathcal{A}_\alpha)$, and let $\mathcal{A}=\bigcup_{\eta<\theta}\mathcal{A}_\eta$. Then no $a_\eta$ is definable in $\mathcal{A}$ from parameters in $\{a_\alpha: \alpha<\eta\}$.

> This is the only way we will use compactness: to guarantee that our theory has proper elementary chains of arbitrary length. Everything else is just flagrant abuse of [vermin and vacancies](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pigeonhole_principle).

---

Now let's show how this lets us get **a pair of mutually undefinable elements** (note that the above is "one-way" only). Let $(\mathcal{A}_\eta)_{\eta<\omega_1+1}$ be a proper elementary chain with union $\mathcal{A}$ *(ok fine, $\mathcal{A}=\mathcal{A}_{\omega_1}$, but meh)*. As before let $a_\eta\in\mathcal{A}_\eta\setminus(\bigcup_{\alpha<\eta}\mathcal{A}_\alpha)$ for $\eta\le\omega_1$, and think about $a_{\omega_1}$. No $a_\eta$ with $\eta<\omega_1$ can define it; conversely, $a_{\omega_1}$ can define at most countably many $a_\eta$s. So for some $\gamma<\omega_1$ we have that neither $a_{\omega_1}$ nor $a_\gamma$ is definable from the other in $\mathcal{A}$; now take a countable elementary submodel of $\mathcal{A}$ containing $a_{\omega_1}$ and $a_\gamma$.

---

Now the fun bit:

**What about building a triple?**

Well, here we need to be careful. We might be tempted to run the same argument as above but with length $\omega_1+\omega_1+1$. If we do this, we get a triple of elements $a_{\omega_1+\omega_1}, a_\eta$ (with $\omega_1<\eta<\omega_1+\omega_1$), $a_\gamma$ (with $\gamma<\omega_1$) such that $a_{\omega_1+\omega_1}$ doesn't define $a_\eta$ and $\{a_\eta, a_{\omega_1+\omega_1}\}$ doesn't define $a_\gamma$; and clearly $\{a_\gamma, a_\eta\}$ won't define $a_{\omega_1+\omega_1}$. However, there's no obvious reason why $a_\eta$ can't be definable from $\{a_\gamma,a_{\omega_1+\omega_1}\}$.

Instead, we need to look at an even longer chain - $(\mathcal{A}_\eta)_{\eta<\omega_2+1}$. *(Below, when we say "definable" we mean "definable in $\bigcup_{\eta<\omega_2+1}\mathcal{A}_\eta$;" and yes, that's just $\mathcal{A}_{\omega_2}$.)*

We again pick elements $a_\eta$ as before, and start at $a_{\omega_2}$. There are $\omega_2$-many indices $\eta$ with $\omega_1<\eta<\omega_2$ such that $a_\eta$ isn't definable from $a_{\omega_2}$; **and for each such $\eta$ there is some $\gamma_\eta<\omega_1$ such that $a_{\gamma_\eta}$ isn't definable from $\{a_\eta, a_{\omega_2}\}$.**

Now consider the map $\eta\mapsto\gamma_\eta$; this is a map from a size-$\omega_2$ set to a size-$\omega_1$ set, so there's some $\gamma<\omega_1$ such that for $\omega_2$-many $\eta$s with $\omega_1<\eta<\omega_2$, we have

- $a_\eta$ is not definable from $a_{\omega_2}$,
- $a_\gamma$ isn't definable from $\{a_\eta, a_{\omega_2}\}$.

Let $E$ be the set of these $\eta$s. Only countably many $\eta\in E$ can have the property that $a_\eta$ is definable from $\{a_\gamma, a_{\omega_2}\}$, so pick some $\theta\in E$ with $a_\theta$ not definable from $\{a_\gamma, a_{\omega_2}\}$; no element of $\{a_\gamma, a_\theta, a_{\omega_2}\}$ is definable from the other two.

Now take a countable elementary submodel of $\mathcal{A}$ containing $\{a_\gamma, a_\theta, a_{\omega_2}\}$. Not so bad, right? All we needed was to go up to $\omega_2$.

**Hehehehehe.**

> Exercise: how long must our chains be to get a set of cardinality $\kappa$, no element of which is definable from the rest?

*Note: in the above, we "counted down" in our chain. Once $\kappa$ is infinite, this obviously isn't going to work, so we need to use the same intuition but instead "count up" the chain.*

Comment: For minimal cardinality of the resulting $\mathcal{A}$, just let $\vert\mathcal{A}_\eta\vert\le\aleph_0\cdot \vert\eta\vert$. In particular, to get a triple we need only consider models of cardinality $\le\aleph_2$.